# Why app.use() don't work in my case also if the path is the same

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to send the dist folder from my server to the client.

If I write the command like this:

```
app.use('/', express.static( Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'del-js-webapp', 'dist') ));
```

it works.
But i want to reach dist with the path /game, so i rewrite the comand like:

```
app.use('/game', express.static( Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'del-js-webapp', 'dist') ));
```

but if i write this it didn't work.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer to WHY, but I did face a similar problem myself in the past and solved it like this:

```
app.use('/pick-stats', express.static('static/pick-stats', {index:false,extensions:['html']}));
app.get('/pick-stats*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/static/pick-stats/index.html')); });
```

2 lines of app.use